# sudo and sssd not working with user groups

Tags: sudo, sssd

Having a problem getting sudo that is integrated with sssd to work correctly when we use ldap to store the groups that have the different sudo privs.  This works just fine if we have sudo set to go to ldap directly.

Here's our scenario.

Have a user defined in ldap: waynea

waynea is member of 2 groups.  One group, gcadmin, allows him to run specific commands as root.  The other group, gcoracle, allows him to run specific commands as the local (not defined in ldap) user oracle.

```
waynea@pgc501> id
uid=5091(waynea) gid=5000(mcsuser) groups=5000(mcsuser),5022(gcadmin),5024(gcoracle)
```

Here's the ldap sudo definition of the 2 groups:

```
waynea@pgc501> ldapsearch -h pld101.foo.com -x "(cn=%gcadmin)"
# %gcadmin, SUDOers, foo.com
dn: cn=%gcadmin,ou=SUDOers,dc=foo,dc=com
cn: %gcadmin
objectClass: sudoRole
objectClass: top
sudoCommand: /usr/bin/id
sudoCommand: /bin/ps
sudoCommand: /u01/oracle/12.1.0/agent12c/agent_inst/bin/emctl
sudoHost: ALL
sudoUser: %gcadmin
sudoRunAs: ALL

waynea@pgc501> ldapsearch -h pld101.foo.com -x "(cn=%gcadmin)"
# %gcoracle, SUDOers, foo.com
dn: cn=%gcoracle,ou=SUDOers,dc=foo,dc=com
cn: %gcoracle
objectClass: sudoRole
objectClass: top
sudoCommand: /bin/sh
sudoCommand: /u01/oracle/12.1.0/agent12c/sbin/nmosudo *
sudoHost: ALL
sudoRunAs: oracle
sudoUser: %gcoracle
```

Now, when we have sudo hooked up directly to ldap.  I.E. /etc/nsswitch.conf has this:

```
sudoers:       files ldap
```

And I issue "sudo -ll", I get this:

```
waynea@pgc501 > sudo -ll
Matching Defaults entries for waynea on this host:
    requiretty, !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL
    PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES",
    env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User waynea may run the following commands on this host:
    RunAsUsers: oracle
    Commands:
        /bin/sh
        /u01/oracle/12.1.0/agent12c/sbin/nmosudo *
    RunAsUsers: root
    Commands:
        /usr/bin/id
        /u01/oracle/12.1.0/agent12c/agent_inst/bin/emctl
```

And everything is just fine.

When we switch sudo to using sssd,

```
sudoers:       files sss
```

we get this:

```
waynea@pgc501 > sudo -ll
Matching Defaults entries for waynea on this host:
    requiretty, !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL
    PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES",
    env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User waynea may run the following commands on this host:
    RunAsUsers: root
    Commands:
        /bin/sh
        /u01/oracle/12.1.0/agent12c/sbin/nmosudo *
    RunAsUsers: root
    Commands:
        /usr/bin/id
        /u01/oracle/12.1.0/agent12c/agent_inst/bin/emctl
```

Which now gives waynea the permission to start a shell (/bin/sh) as root.

Here are the relevant entries from /etc/sssd/sssd.conf.

```
[domain/default]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
sudo_provider = ldap
ldap_sudo_search_base = ou=SUDOers,dc=foo,dc=com
ldap_uri = ldap://pld101.foo.com,ldap://pld301.foo.com/
ldap_search_base = dc=foo,dc=com
ldap_user_search_base = ou=People,dc=foo,dc=com
ldap_group_object_class = posixGroup
ldap_group_search_base = ou=Group,dc=foo,dc=com
ldap_group_name = cn
ldap_group_member = memberUid
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
chpass_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = true

[sudo]
ldap_sudo_full_refresh_interval = 86400
ldap_sudo_smart_refresh_interval = 3600
```

Any help would be appreciated!  We would like to take advantage of sssd, but this is somewhat of a showstopper.

Here's the OS/rpm versions:

```
Linux 6.5  (OEL)
sssd-1.9.2-129.el6_5.4.x86_64
sudo-1.8.6p3-12.el6.x86_64
libsss_sudo-1.9.2-129.el6_5.4.x86_64
sssd-client-1.9.2-129.el6_5.4.x86_64
```

Comment: have you ever found out the solution? I'm hitting the exact same problem, when sudoUser and sudoHost is a group it doesn't work.

Comment: It's been a while, that the details are somewhat vague, but I think we resolved it by upgrading the sssd version.  We were on version 1.9.2, and I think we resolved the issue by upgrading to 1.11.6.  We also went from sudo-1.8.6p3-12 to 1.8.6p3-15 (but I don't think that had an effect).

Answer (score 1):

user `waynea` need to logout and login again

---

`sudo -ll` print like this:

```
[WanJie@svr-master root]$ sudo -ll
Matching Defaults entries for WanJie on this host:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION
    LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin, !visiblepw,
    always_set_home, env_reset, requiretty
```

User `WanJie` may run the following commands on this host:

```
SSSD Role: %admin
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Options: !authenticate
    Commands:
        /root/aaa.sh

SSSD Role: WanJie
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Options: !authenticate
    Commands:
        /root/sudo.sh
```